# Graphs in plotly-dash app not updating in real time

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am new to plotly-dash and I am trying to have 4 graphs in the dashboard. My dash app is connected to Cassandra database which is streaming live data from kafka. I am able to plot all 4 graphs as per the requirement but the graphs are not getting updated as per the new data. I tried refreshing the page but still no progress. I have to stop and run the python app again and again in order to get the updated graphs.

Here is the dash app code

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from jupyter_dash import JupyterDash
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

#getting conection with cassandra
cluster = Cluster()
session = cluster.connect('test')

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

# assume you have a "long-form" data frame
# see https://plotly.com/python/px-arguments/ for more options
df = session.execute('select txn_type, dept, predicted_sla, currency, amount, cr_cust_type, predicted_stp, dr_cust_type, department_sla from response')
df = pd.DataFrame(df[:])

df_sla = df.groupby(['dept','predicted_sla']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

df_pie = df[df['predicted_sla'] == 'NOT MET']
df_priority = df_pie.groupby(['dr_cust_type','predicted_sla']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

df_stp = df.groupby(['dept','predicted_stp']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

df_actual_sla = df.groupby(['dept','department_sla']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})

fig = px.bar(df_sla, x="dept", y="count", color="predicted_sla", barmode="group")
fig2 = px.pie(df_priority, values='count', names='dr_cust_type', hole=.3)
fig3 = px.bar(df_stp, x="dept", y="count", color="predicted_stp", barmode="group")
fig4 = px.bar(df_actual_sla, x="dept", y="count", color="department_sla", barmode="group")

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    # All elements from the top of the page
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Dash: A web application framework for Python.
            '''),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph1',
                figure=fig
            ),  
        ], className='six columns'),
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Dash: A web application framework for Python.
            '''),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph2',
                figure=fig2
            ),  
        ], className='six columns'),
    ], className='row'),


    # New Div for all elements in the new 'row' of the page
html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Dash: A web application framework for Python.
            '''),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph3',
                figure=fig3
            ),  
        ], className='six columns'),
        html.Div([
            html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

            html.Div(children='''
                Dash: A web application framework for Python.
            '''),

            dcc.Graph(
                id='graph4',
                figure=fig4
            ),  
        ], className='six columns'),
    ], className='row'),
    
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Python version is 3.8.10 and dash version is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 0):

You will want something like a button that when clicked updates your data OR [a callback to update your data at some frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63376614/2516746).